# RoR undefined method

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Ive had a problem for a couple of days. I've tried every solotion thad i found on stackoverflow, but nothing worked...

Rails gives me an error when i try to add a new 'journey' (just a simple datapase entry): undefined method `journeys_index_path' for #<#:0x3d0b888>

Problem resolved!
The issue was the model name. It was Journeys but it should be journey ! The only thing I had to do is rename the modelfile in app/models. (i had to change the filename and the contents, pretty simple!

Oh and the model name is not the same as the database name. 
Please check http://rubyonrailsthrissur.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/naming-conventions-while-creating-tables-in-rails/ for more naming rules

Routes.rb:

```
Fabulam::Application.routes.draw do
 root "home#home"
 resources :journeys
 match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create', via: 'get'
 match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/'),  via: 'get'
 match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: 'get', as: 'signout'

end
```

journeys_controller (relevant part)

```
def index
@current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
@journey = Journeys.where(uid:   current_user.uid)
end

def show
 @journey = Journeys.find(params[:id])
end

def new
 @journey = Journeys.new
end
```

new.html.erb (location = journeys/new.html.erb)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>
<h1> Maak hieronder een nieuwe reis aan! </h1>

<% form_for(@journey) do |f| %>
    <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br/<
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </P>
    <p>
    <%f.submit "Dubmittt" %>
    </p>
<% end %>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html.erb (location journeys/index.html.erb, this one is working fine)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="user_nav">
  <% if current_user %>
    Signed in as <strong><%= current_user.name %></strong>!
    <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, id: "sign_out" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook", id: "sign_in" %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div id="travels">
Hieronder al je reizen!
<% @journey.each do |journey| %>
    <h2><%=  link_to journey.name, journey %></h2>
<% end %> 
</div>

<p><%= link_to "Add a new journey" , new_journey_path %> </P>

</body>
</html>
```

Rake routes

```
  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                        Controller#Action
    root GET    /                                  home#home
 journeys GET    /journeys(.:format)                journeys#index
         POST   /journeys(.:format)                journeys#create
 new_journey GET    /journeys/new(.:format)            journeys#new
 edit_journey GET    /journeys/:id/edit(.:format)       journeys#edit
 journey GET    /journeys/:id(.:format)            journeys#show
         PATCH  /journeys/:id(.:format)            journeys#update
         PUT    /journeys/:id(.:format)            journeys#update
         DELETE /journeys/:id(.:format)            journeys#destroy
         GET    /auth/:provider/callback(.:format) sessions#create
 auth_failure GET    /auth/failure(.:format)            redirect(301, /)
 signout GET    /signout(.:format)                 sessions#destroy
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does this error occur (ie: is it when you go to /journeys/new)? Please add the entire stack trace to your question.

Comment: Please add the entire `routes.rb` file and your controller actions, at least `create`.

Comment: Thanks for yor reply! i will update my question with the complete routes.rb. The error occurs when i go to journeys/new.